# Comparing timestamps continuously

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to send an `unlockTime` prop to a `component1` so that `component 1` will render after the `unlockTime` has passed.

How can I get vue to keep checking if the `unlockTime` has passed (`Date.now() > this.unlockTime ? true : false`)?

**Main.vue:**

```
<template>
<component1
  :unlockTime="unlockTime">
</component1>
</template>

<script>
  computed: {
    unlockTime() {
      return Date.now() + (5 * 60 * 1000)
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Component1.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="unlock">
    Some Content Here
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  props: ["unlockTime"]

  data(){
    return{
      unlock: Date.now() > this.unlockTime ? true : false
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution:

1. Uses `setInterval` to get current date time
2. Uses **watcher**/**computed** to update data property=**isLock** by comparing current date time and unlock date time.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div>
              <p v-show="isLock"><span>Waiting for Unlock...{{unlock}} - {{currentDateTime}}</span></p>
              <p v-show="computedIsLock"><i>computed lock:{{computedIsLock}}</i></p>
             </div>`,
  props: ['unlock'],
  created: function () {
    this.intervalMgr = setInterval(()=>{
      this.currentDateTime = new Date()
    }, 500)
    this.isLock = this.currentDateTime < this.unlock
  },
  data(){
    return {
      isLock: true,
      currentDateTime: new Date(),
      intervalMgr: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedIsLock: function () {
      return this.currentDateTime < this.unlock
    }
  },
  watch: {
    currentDateTime: function (newVal) {
      this.isLock = newVal < this.unlock
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy: function () {
    clearInterval(this.intervalMgr)
  }
})

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    unlockTime: new Date()
  },
  created: function () {
    this.addTime()
  },
  methods: {
    addTime: function () {
      this.unlockTime = new Date()
      this.unlockTime.setSeconds(this.unlockTime.getSeconds() + 5)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="addTime()">Add Time</button>
    <child :unlock="unlockTime"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: when I log `this.isLock = this.currentDateTime < this.unlock`, it's always showing false. The time is being shown as something like `1533831220641` but the expression is not evaluated properly. Any idea why that is? Everything else looks good.

Comment: so you are saying the `this.isLock = this.currentDateTime < this.unlock` inside `hook=created()`? can you post your sample into one jsfiddle?

Comment: When I put `this.isLock = this.currentDateTime < this.unlock` inside the interval, it works :)

Comment: @jj008 you put the `this.isLock = this.currentDateTime < this.unlock` into the `setInterval`?

Comment: Yes, `created: function () {
    this.intervalMgr = setInterval(()=>{
      this.currentDateTime = new Date()
      this.isLock = this.currentDateTime < this.unlock
    }, 500)
  }`

Comment: So every 500ms, it will check if the component should be locked/unlocked

Comment: In terms of performance, would it be too much if I set the interval to 100ms so it feels even more responsive?